# performing query with priority in mongo

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

sample document :

```
{"name":"John", "age":35, "level":"trainee",.....}
```

1. Employees whose join_month=3 is top priority (employees in this category appear first)
2. Employees who are supervisors are second priority (appear after all employees in #1)
3. Employees who are not Malaysian has lowest priority (appear after all other employees)

Example :

1. John and Jane joined in March
2. Adam, John and Bob are supervisors
3. all previously mentioned employees above plus Lee are not Malaysian

the expected results are:

```
[John, Jane], [Adam, Bob], [Lee]
```

the square brackets above is to show that the order within the same square bracket doesnt matter. So Jane may also appear before John (cause they're in the same criteria). but both John and Jane MUST appear before Adam and Bob since join_month=3 has higher priority that level=supervisor. and also notice that even when John also meets level=supervisor criteria, he's not included again since he already meets join_month=3.

is this doable in MongoDB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL query, you don't need the `UNION` operator because you are selecting from the same table. You should use the `OR` operator. MongoDB provides a [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator which does what you want.

Your SQL query:

```
SELECT NAME, AGE FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE JOIN_MONTH=3
OR LEVEL='SUPERVISOR'
OR NATIONALITY <> 'MY'
```

In MongoDB:

```
db.EMPLOYEE.find( { 
    "$or": [ 
        { "join_month": 3 }, 
        { "level": "supervisor" }, 
        { "nationality": { "$ne": "my" } } 
     ] },
     { "name": 1, "_id": 0, "age": 1 }
)
```

Everything you need is in the documentation. You should start from the official [MongoDB CRUD Tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/crud/) and a take a look at the [SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/)

If you want to sort the result based on the some fields value then you need to use the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline. The first stage in the pipeline is the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage where you select only those documents that match your criteria. This also reduce the size of document to process in the next stage which is here, the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage where you use the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator to return a value for a field that you will use to sort the query result in the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) stage. This process is called ["weighting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighting)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "$or": [ 
            { "join_month": 3 }, 
            { "level": "supervisor" }, 
            { "nationality": { "$ne": "MY" } }
        ] 
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "name": 1, 
        "age": 1,
        "_id": 0, 
        "criteria": { 
            "$cond": [ 
               { "$eq": [ "$join_month",  3 ] }, 
               3, 
               { "$cond": [ 
                   { "$eq": [ "$level", "supervisor" ] }, 
                   2 , 
                   1 
               ] } 
            ] 
        } 
    }}, 
    { "$sort":  { "criteria": -1 } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need ordering, you may use aggregation as below.

```
pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {$or: [{join_months: 3}, {level: 'Supervisor'}, {nationality: {$ne: 'MY'}}
                  ]}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      age: 1,
      join_priority: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$join_months', 3]}, 1, 0]},
      leve_priority: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$level', 'supervisor']}, 1, 0]},
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {join_priority: -1, level_priority: -1}
  }
];
db.mycollection.aggregate(pipeline);
```